# Ubuntu 12.10 gets stuck at startup (laptop)

Tags: 12.10, startup, bootloader

I have noticed that almost 30% of the times, ubuntu gets stuck at the "purple" screen before the actual Ubuntu symbol comes when the OS loads.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

PS: I have this peculiar entry in boot menu. 1st its "Ubuntu" and then when I choose the other option it takes me to the 3.2's generic and safe kernel version. Interestingly I am using the 3.5.0-17 generic version of the kernel. (is this the latest for ubuntu?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem too. However, it helps to move your mouse during boot. Doesn't happen when grub is in hidden boot. If you aren't multibooting, try edit /etc/default/grub to enable hidden boot.